# Is it possible to pass a HTML value into a Less function?

Tags: html, css, less

The replace function in less takes a string as it first parameter such as:

```
replace('test','test','replaced');
```

replace would return `replaced` in this case. but can you uses a variable like this:

```
replace(@text,'test','replaced');
```

My use case would be to dynamically change an attribute of a div tag and then have replace function change the content. This would be something like this:

```css
div:before{
  @text : attr(title);
  //content:@text;
  content:replace(@text,'test','replaced');
}
```

```html
<div title="test"></div> <-- title would be changed dynamically -->
```

less seems to not allow this. Is there a way to use variable strings with replace? Is there another way to dynamically change the text without javascript/jquery?

Comment: Less is compiled *before* its put into any HTML so it simply can't know what the `title` attribute of a HTML element could be.

Comment: Duh why did I not see that . Thanks for the info

Comment: You should not use `content` for user-facing textual content anyway.